# How can I retain color of original image after using overlay option

Tags: adobe-photoshop, overlay

How am I able to retain the exact original color (the blue lions) after using the overlay option?

[image: Shield 1]

[image: Shield 2]

As you can see, after using the overlay the blue lions feel like they are part of the shield (scratches and stuff), but they change color. I want them to remain blue (exact original color) while feeling as an overlay.

Answer (score 1):

A layer mask would probably be the best way to go about this in Photoshop.  Select the layer with the overlay and click the layer mask icon at the bottom of the Layers palette:

[image]

Paint the layer mask with the brush tool in black to block out any of the overlay layer:

[image]